# gtest DEATH_TEST complains about fork() and threads, but only threads found had been joined

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11, fork

I'm using gtest for unit testing and, in particular, have some DEATH_TESTS for some assertions in debug builds. To `SetUp()` the test, I have to create an object which creates another thread, goes off and does some work, returns some data, and then joins on the object's thread. Finally the test fixture's `SetUp()` returns, allowing the test body to run.

I've noticed that sometimes DEATH_TEST will complain `Death tests use fork(), which is unsafe particularly in a threaded context. For this test, Google Test detected 2 threads.` which is, of course, a valid problem *if there's actually multiple threads running*. Sometimes, however, no such warning exists. It seems like a race condition.

So looking into it, I discovered that gtest is using `/proc/self/task` pseudo filesystem to discover threads. Since all of my threads are named, I decided to use `/proc/self/task/[tid]/comm` to discover which thread might be lingering. Indeed, it's the exact same thread which was `join()`ed. So I came up with an example source code to reproduce the issue which **1)** reproduces gtest's thread detection for gtest, and **2)** if the target thread is lingering, then emits a message to stdout.

```
// g++ test.cpp --std=c++11 -pthread
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include <dirent.h> // DIR*, dirent*, opendir(), closedir(); enumerate pseudo-fs /proc/self/task
#include <string.h> // strcmp();

#include <sys/prctl.h> // prctl(), PR_SET_NAME; sets name of current thread

std::string get_thread_name(std::string tid_str) {
    std::fstream f(std::string("/proc/self/task/") + tid_str + std::string("/comm"));
    tid_str.clear();
    std::getline(f, tid_str);
    return tid_str;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // until SIGTERM (ctrl-c)
    while (true) {
        std::thread a([](){
            prctl(PR_SET_NAME,"TARGET",0,0,0);
        });
        a.join();
        if (DIR *dir = opendir("/proc/self/task")) {
            bool found = false;
            while (dirent *entry = readdir(dir)) {
                if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0) {
                    std::string name = get_thread_name(entry->d_name);
                    if ( found = (name == "TARGET") ) {
                        std::cout << "THREAD " << entry->d_name << " -- " << name << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir(dir);
            if ( not found ) {
                std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "Cannot enumerate" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using Ubuntu 14.04 and GCC 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 and the command as commented on the first line of the example source, I end up with output to stdout indicating that the race condition does seem to exist. Most of the output states "Not found", while sometimes the output is interspersed with the TID of the TARGET-named thread. I could disable the output of "Not found" and observe that the emitted TID changes.

In working on this, I discovered that a system's thread id (`[tid]` in `/proc/self/task/[tid]`) is different from pthread's `pthread_t` as expected in `pthread_getname_np()`. I discovered that there is `prctl` with `PR_GET_NAME` but that appears to only retrieve the name of the current (calling) thread. So one of my questions is: **is there a documented API to retrieve a thread's name if given a system TID (eg, so you don't have to read `/proc/self/task/[tid]/comm`)?** But that's only a side question.

More importantly, **is there a way to guarantee that this is a false positive as far as `fork()` problems are concerned?**, and related question: **is there a better way to ensure that a `std::thread` has actually finished than to `join()`**?

Comment: Have you read this: https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Death_Tests_And_Threads ?  They mention "well-known problems with forking in the presence of threads" - but I do not know this problem...

Comment: Yes, I've read it and that's what my questions are trying to discuss -- trying to ensure that only one single thread exists (the main thread). All of the static libs I'm using don't create their own thread. Further, I provided a MCVE which does not have third party static libs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I think that w/o tracking system TID <-> pthread ID mappings yourself you're out of luck; the pthread ID is an opaque value specifically to decouple it from platform-specific process abstractions and I don't believe there are any public APIs to extract it.
2. I think that your procfs & `std::thread::join` / `pthread_join` race is probably unavoidable, at least in present Linux implementations. `pthread_join` waits for the kernel to clear a registered memory location & signal a futex during thread exit. This happens in `mm_release` (*linux/kernel/fork.c*) which is invoked right in the middle of `do_exit`, before all of the task accounting structures are updated. I suspect that traversing procfs immediately after `pthread_join` completes can easily race with the rest of process teardown.

A dissatisfying answer in terms of the problem you're trying to solve, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Dissatisfying in some ways, but it does point me in the direction of where to read in the kernel. That's helpful at least. It looks like the same `do_exit` function tries to set `tsk->state = TASK_DEAD`. I wonder if *a future version of the Linux kernel* could set the task state to some state which indicates *the task is exiting* prior to doing any join-signal-releasing execution. That could then be checked and polled against? A brief search on google for "linux get task state" doesn't reveal an API to retrieve a task's state if given a pid or tid though. More research needed on my part.